# HA for Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Is there a way to run Spring Cloud Gateway as a websocket gateway in a cluster, and if one of the nodes goes down, the others take over without causing much disruption for the gateway's clients and the proxied server?

Comment: No, it is a stateless service. It would still behind some kind of hardware or software load balancer.

Comment: In the case of HTTP requests, I understand it's stateless, but thought that for websockets it would be a different case. Does Gateway not have a websocket subscription registry to keep track which client subscribed to which topic? Also, if one of the gateway instances is subscribed to a topic at the proxied websocket server, and that instance dies, wouldn't another gateway instance need to subscribe to that topic so the client would still keep receiving  messages?

Comment: For example, Zuul 2 has a global registry for subscriptions to handle that (https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/Push-Messaging) and I was assuming gateway would need something similar, too.

Comment: I don't think the registry implies HA, they recommend still putting it behind a load balancer https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/Push-Messaging#load-balancers-vs-websockets-and-sse

Comment: Load balancer can be sorted out (I'm using GCP). Right now I'm building custom solution using Spring websocket and Redis for registry, and would love to use the gateway instead. Unfortunately, having a single instance is not an option.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. No one ever runs a single gateway or zuul. And it's always behind a load balancer

Comment: Agree, you should never run it as a single instance. Once you stick a LB in front of it, you can also enhance it by adding it to an auto-scaling group if you're using AWS or similar so it scales it up/down depending on traffic.

Comment: Adding more gateway instances under the LB may work for HTTP requests, as gateway can handle them in a stateless fashion.

However, this would not work for websockets, as that would require tracking subscriptions in a distributed store (see my earlier message on global registry for Zuul v2).

I got the impression from @spencergibb that this is not something currently supported in gateway.

Comment: And I'm telling you with the link I sent that Netflix **recommends** putting zuul 2 behind a load balancer. It's registry **is not** distributed, but local to the zuul 2 instance.

Comment: I get it that a load balancer is a must when having multiple instances, but I may be missing something on how a load balancer can solve the issue around local registries. According to Netflix: "In case of a multi-node push cluster, a second level, off-the box global datastore is needed to extend push registry beyond the single machine."

Once an instance goes down, its local registry information will be lost, hence no other instance will be able to subscribe to those topics on the proxied server or know which client should receive messages from which topics. 

Am I missing something here?

Comment: @kaviddiss from my reading of that page, this is not what the registry is for. A connection is stateful and therefore cannot be transparently moved on node failure. What the registry does is allow the Zuul cluster to route push notifications to the right node. The servers pushing messages can just push at the cluster and the cluster will route the message internally. Also note the caveats towards the bottom of that page around using traditional load balancers with stateful protocols.

Comment: @kaviddiss "_In such case lookup for a particular client follows a two step process. First, you **lookup the push server to which the specified client is connected** in the off-the-box, global push registry. That lookup returns the push server which can then **look up the actual client connection within its local, in-memory push registry**._" What you are asking for is not possible AFAIK.